# CPT - Can't delete Draft posts

Tags: custom-post-types

Here's my issue.
I have a CPT called cikkek, and authors created about 260 drafts which I would like to clean up. I navigate to the admin screen, and select all twenty of them.

Then I click on the dropdown and tell it to delete all of them.

The page reloads, and nothing happens.
Nothing related found in the console. Anyone had experience with such an issue?

Comment: Have you tried deleting one at a time?

Comment: Thanks, managed to fix it fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. First I tried to disable plugins but that did not help.
The issue was found in functions.php.

It had a function inside that does not allow an article to be published unless it has a featured image. When I commented it out and tried deleting the articles, it started working again. Unsure as to why trashing and publishing are related in this instance, but that's that.